# string replace in a file with php

Tags: php, parsing

I am writing an email module for my web app that sends a html email to a user on completion of a task such as signing up.  Now as the formatting of this email may change I've decided to have a template html page that is the email, with custom tags in it that need to be replaced such as %fullname%.

My function has an array in the format of array(%fullname% => 'Joe Bloggs'); with the key as the tag identifier and the value of what needs to replace it.

I've tried the following:

```
        $fp = @fopen('email.html', 'r');

    if($fp)
    {
      while(!feof($fp)){

      $line = fgets($fp);                 

      foreach($data as $value){

          echo $value;
          $repstr = str_replace(key($data), $value, $line);           

      }


      $content .= $repstr;

      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
```

Is this the best way to do this? as only 1 tag get replaced at the moment... am I on the right path or miles off??

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in your foreach. This should fix it:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $repstr = str_replace($key, $value, $line);               
}
```

Alternatively, I think this should be more effective:

```
$file = @file_get_contents("email.html");
if($file) {
    $file = str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $file);
    print $file;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//read the entire string
$str=implode("\n",file('somefile.txt'));

$fp=fopen('somefile.txt','w');
//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace('Yankees','Cardinals',$str);

//now, TOTALLY rewrite the file
fwrite($fp,$str,strlen($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work, but I'd use "file_get_contents()" and do it in one big blast.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach is to use PHP's heredocs combined with string interpolation i.e.:

```
$email = <<<EOD
<HTML><BODY>
Hi $fullname,
  You have just signed up.
</BODY></HTML>
EOD;
```

This avoids a separate file, and should make things beyond simple substitution easier later.